# Rabbitmq Per channel thread or per channel process while using python

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, pika

Writing an python processor which will handle message from different channel. What should be good way, i.e. different process for processing different channel or different thread for processing over different channel.

Please let me know, if the question is unclear or need any other information.

Comment: What kind of processing are you doing with each message?

Comment: Most possibly all kinds: database bound, cpu bound, web service bound.

Comment: Also, time might vary from few seconds to some longer tasks which might take upto 5 minutes.

Comment: It depends more on what kind of Python processing you are doing. If you may run into GlobalInterpreterLock issues you may want multiple process, but if that isn't the case threads are just fine. I would however recommend that you read through the documentation for the library you choose, as most AMQP libraries are not thread safe. 

I have a couple of examples on how to implement a threaded consumer for my library here if you are interested: https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm/tree/master/examples